# How to check if a geometry of type Point is inside another geometry of type MultiPolygonZM using Postgis functions?

Tags: postgis

I want to know if there's a way to check if a geometry of type Point is inside a geometry of type MultiPolygonZM, ignoring the Z coordinate, I just want to know if my Point(lat, lng) is inside a MultiPolygonZM.

This is an example of a MultiPolygonZM geometry in my database; I used **ST_AsText** to get a text representation of the geom :

```
"MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((
570277.5312 3592073.8077 460.900200000004 -1.79769313486232e+308,
570262.0283 3592073.7806 460.712700000004 -1.79769313486232e+308,
570262.4922 3592086.4664 460.705199999997 -1.79769313486232e+308,
570278.0406 3592086.5792 460.697700000004  (...)"
```

I tried `ST_CONTAINS`, `ST_INTERSECTS` like this :

```
SELECT * FROM CITIES
WHERE
ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(3.67622580, 32.48549230), 4326))

SELECT * FROM CITIES
WHERE
ST_Contains(ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(3.67622580, 32.48549230), 4326)).
```

My table uses 4326 as **SRID**, but i wanted to set it using **ST_SetSRID** to be sure that all the geoms have the same **SRID**

But it doesn't work! All the results are false!

Any solution ?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the SRID of the polygon table. You appear to be misusing ST_SetSRID instead of the proper ST_Transform in that context, meaning that dimensionality has *nothing* to do with the contains failure. In order to use the spatial index you need to transform the point into the polygon table's SRID.

Comment: Note that "Point (lat,lon)" reverses proper order (it should be "lon,lat"), which will also scramble topology tests.

Comment: I used ST_SetSRID to be sure that all the geoms have the same SRID, and i tried to switch between lat long it doesn't work...
Edited

Comment: OK, you proplem is that those coordinates are not 4326. So, you need to find out whatever coordinate system that is and use ST_Transform(ST_Setsrid(geom, srid), 4326)) where srid is your actual srid. ST_SetSRID only sets it, it does not do any transforming.  You should update your geometry srid, as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: My problem is that my table has SRID 4326 but the coordinate aren't in the same SRID, they are in 32631. So i changed my table's SRDI to 32631 then transform my geom from 32631 to 4326 and it worked! :D Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either **ST_Contains** or **ST_Intersects** should work. You can use [ST_Force_2D](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Force_2D.html) to make a polygon be 2D only.

However, this does **not** affect the results of an intersect. Note that both of the following, which only differ in a **ST_Force2D** function, return true (t):

```
SELECT  
    ST_Intersects(
          ST_Force2d(
               ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0 2,0 5 2,5 0 2,0 0 2))')),
               ST_MakePoint(2,2));

SELECT  
     ST_Intersects(
            ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0 2,0 5 2,5 0 2,0 0 2))'),
            ST_MakePoint(2,2));
```

So, it is possible that your problem lies elsewhere. If you could provide an example of one of your PolygonZM that you think should intersect a point, it would be easier to investigate.

Also, it is generally not a good idea to use [ST_SetSRID](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) in queries, but to update the columns using [UpdateGeometrySRID](https://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html). This will have the additional benefit of updating the geometry_columns meta data table, making errors involving different SRIDs impossible and generally keeping your db cleaner and your queries shorter. If you need to use a different SRID, you can always use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html).

One form, if you exclude the schema name, would be:

```
SELECT updategeometrysrid('cities', 'geom', 4326);
```

Comment: I edited my question and add an example of a MultiPolygonZM